# Best Algorithm to distribute n elements to x groups

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

What is the best way to distribute `n` items (say 2 up to 100) into x groups.
Each group should have about the same amount of items in it.

Easy example would be `n=100; x=2;`

> 100/2 = 50 items per group

What if we've got floating numbers involved, like `n=100; x=3;`

> 100/3 = 33.33

We would need two groups nesting 33 items and one group nesting 34.
Another example: `n=8; x=3`

> 8/3 = 2.66

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Not that it matters, but just for curious minds, the usecase:
In my UI im trying to divide tabstripes into multiple rows, only showing one row at a time, so that if all the tabstripes don't fit into one row we can distribute them programmatically.

Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After distributing `floor(n / x)` items over `x` groups you're left with `n mod x = n - floor(n / x) * x` items, that's a value in `[0, x)`. You can easily add `1` to each group `i=1..x` with `i <= n mod x`.

```
for i=1..x
   group[i] <- floor(n / x) + (i <= n mod x ? 1 : 0)
```

this is the same as

```
for i=1..(n mod x)
   group[i] <- ceil(n / x)
for i=(n mod x + 1)..x
   group[i] <- floor(n / x)
```

E.g. `n = 11, x = 3` you'll end up with:

```
group[1] <- 3 + (1 <= 2 ? 1 : 0) = 4
group[2] <- 3 + (2 <= 2 ? 1 : 0) = 4
group[3] <- 3 + (3 <= 2 ? 1 : 0) = 3
```

Comment: just to be super precise, the modulo operation returns a value between [0, x-1] :-)

Comment: @JanBenda that's the same as the [(right-open) interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints) `[0, x)` when talking about integers: `[0, x-1] == {i | 0 <= i <= x-1} == {i | 0 <= i < x} == [0, x)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your groups are in some form of arrays indexed from 0 with 'groupCount' groups, a simple distribution "by rows" would be something like:

```
g = 0
for each element e
    allocate e to group groups[g]
    g++
    g = (g % groupCount)
```

If the allocation to a group one element at a time is too slow, it can be faster to allocate 'by columns'. Assuming that the counters 'remainingElements' and 'remainingGroups' are initialized appropriately, it would look like:

```
for each group g
    size = floor(remainingElements / remainingGroups)
    allocate size elements to group g
    remainingElements = remainingElements - size
    --remainingGroups
```